# Why does the AND() condition/function doesn't work with ArrayFomula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

`AND` function: If I remove the Arrayformula() it works fine but It doesn't work with Array Formula.
Can I know the reason for it?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(G3:G),IF(AND( G3:G>=7.5,G3:G<=8),"Full Day",IF(AND(G3:G>8,G3:G<24) ,"Full Day+",IF(AND(G3<7.5,G3>=4),"Half Day",IF(G3<4,"Short Leave",)))),))
```