# Google sheets - Check all TRUE per row in boolean 2D array with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I have the following data (created through a `ARRAYFORMULA` formula):

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 2 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 3 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |

If in a row all values are TRUE, the output for that row should be TRUE. If even 1 is FALSE, it should be FALSE instead.
So a formula on the above table should output this:

|  | E |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | TRUE |
| 3 | FALSE |

### Restrictions

- The 1st table's size is not fixed. There could be more columns or rows. Therefore, no manual row by row check.
- It should be 1 function that outputs to multiple rows (like the 2nd table), therefore it should be through the `ARRAYFORMULA` formula (not dragging a cell down, as this works badly when adding rows/columns at a later stage).

### What I tried

#### AND

`AND`, but that gives only a single output:

```
=AND(A1:D3)
# FALSE
```

Also, [AND doesn't work with ARRAYFORMULA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425099/why-does-the-and-condition-function-doesnt-work-with-arrayfomula/64425306#64425306)

#### *

A `*` function as AND in ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A3*B1:B3*C1:C3)
```

Problems are:

- This is a manual process, which doesn't scale.
- If a column is added later, it will become e.g. `A1:A3*C1:C3*D1:D3` instead of `A1:A3*B1:B3*C1:C3*D1:D3`

#### A1:C3*

Unfortunately, this logic is not accepted:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:C3*)
```

#### QUERY

Maybe a QUERY can provide this logic? But I'm not able to come up with how that query should look like.

### Question

How do I do a row-wise check if all values are TRUE with a single ARRAYFORMULA function (taking into account the restrictions mentioned)?

Comment: Does it meet your requirement? `=ArrayFormula(MMULT(N(A1:D3),N(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:D3)^0)))=COLUMNS(A1:D3))`

Comment: @idfurw Your formula is working, thanks! But the sample data I gave is actually output of another ArrayFormula. I don't know how to use your formula without triplicating my code (which is only `A1:D3` for this example).
I think it still might help other people, so can you add it as an answer (preferably with explanation what it does)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B1:E3*1),,9^9)), "0")=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @player0, this works for the sample data! Could you explain a bit more what everything does? Why 2`,,`? What does the `9^9` do? What about the `"0"`? And how do INDEX and REGEXMATCH work here?

Comment: @NumesSanguis sure. we take the range and multiply it by 1 to convert TRUE/FALSE into 1/0 then we smash all columns into one single column with FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(. within a query we skip 2nd argument (hence the 2 commas ,,) 9^9 is a big number. it can be any number you like if its higher than sum of all rows of the range (think of it as "smash all rows") then we regex it by trying to find 0 in the string (eg. 1111 will output FALSE and 1011 will produce TRUE) then we just flip the logic and that's it